# How to check for the cassandra data base table have data or not in java

Tags: java, cassandra

I have code for creting a table. i need to call insert only when there is no data available.

```
        public void createGeoConfigDB(){
                CqlSession session = null;
                try {
                        session = CassandraConnector.getInstance().connect();
                        session.execute(table_query);
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        log.error("Exception in creating db:: "+e);
                } finally {
                        CassandraConnector.getInstance().closeSession(session);
                }
//i need to check condition whether database table have data or not
                insertConfig();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cassandra, there is a concept of conditional writes called "lightweight transactions".

You could check for the existence or non-existence of data with the following CQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (...) VALUES (...) IF EXISTS
```

The negative `IF NOT EXISTS` also works. Cheers!

Comment: `cassandra@cqlsh:rsn_threat> INSERT INTO geoconfig (key , enabled , geo_url , geo_lickey , port ) VALUES ( 1,true,'e','d',12) IF NOT EXISTS ; NoHostAvailable:`
getting this exception if use following .

Answer (score 1):

You can use lightweight transactions for conditional writes in cassandra.

```
cqlsh> INSERT INTO cycling.cyclist_name (id, lastname, firstname)
  VALUES (4647f6d3-7bd2-4085-8d6c-1229351b5498, 'KNETEMANN', 'Roxxane')
  IF NOT EXISTS;
```

To see further information visit
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html

Comment: cassandra@cqlsh:rsn_threat> INSERT INTO geoconfig (key , enabled , geo_url , geo_lickey , port ) VALUES ( 1,true,'e','d',12) IF NOT EXISTS ;
NoHostAvailable:

getting this